# Synchronizing Child-Parent with Signals and Pause

Tags: c, signals, wait, kill, pause

I am playing around with some c code, trying to have a series of children processes do some asynchronous work, followed by some synchronous work.

The parent is in charge of organizing the synchronous nature of the children.

Here is the general idea in code:

```
#define CHILDREN 5

void myHandle(int d) {}

int main () {
    int i;
    int pid[CHILDREN];
    signal(SIGUSR1, myHandle);
    for(i = 0 ; i < CHILDREN ; i++ ){
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid[i] == 0 ){

            // DO SOME ASYNCHRONOUS WORK

            // tell my parent I am done:
            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1); 

            // wait for parent to wake me up.
            pause();

            // DO SOME SYNCHRONOUS WORK

            //wake parent back up.
            kill(getppid() , SIGUSR1);

            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Wait for all children to finish async work:
    for (i = 0 ; i < CHILDREN ; i++) {
        pause(); // ISSUE IS HERE
    }

    // wake children back up in order:
    for (i = 0 ; i < CHILDREN ; i++ ) {
        kill(pid[i], SIGUSR1);
        // wait for child to finish work.
        pause();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code actually works (most of the time). The problem is with the parent pausing in a for loop. In some cases, the multiple children finish their asynchronous work at the same time, resulting in many calls of kill towards the parent. The loop can not iterate fast enough for the parent to be in a paused state for all of the kill calls, causing the program to get stuck on a pause which did not receive a signal.

Any help or recommendations would be great - thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to have an array of size CHILDREN in your main function. And when a child is done, put a value in his element of the array. Then the father just has to check if all flags in the array are up.

This way, there won't be write conflicts between the children, because they each have their own zone

Comment: The only problem with this is that the father will need to be in an active waiting, constantly checking if the flags are up. Whereas in your solution, the pause() makes this a passive wait

Comment: I'll use a sleep in the loop so it isn't "too" busy

Comment: There is a problem here  -> the parent is unable to see the child's array, they have two different copies of the same array.

Comment: Oh, true, the memory is copied and not shared. 
Then you can have a look at the mmap function, that creates a shared file. So the children will work on the same array.
Other possibility, heavier, is to make threads, with pthread library, instead of fork(). The threads do share the memory.